# iOS is it possible to change the image of a button and populate a label with text with the press of one button?

Tags: ios, uibutton, label

I want to be able to change the image of a button, from no tick to a tick, and also populate a label with text all from one press of a button. Is this possible at all?

Here is the code I have so far button cannot make it work:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize locLabel;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (IBAction)pickImage:(id)sender {

    UIImage *btnImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SubmitBooking-pressed.jpg"];
    [sender setImage:btnImage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    locLabel.text = @"Red";
}
```

Many Thanks

**UPDATE**

It seems to be throwing me back to the .h file and highlighting the

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *locLabel;
```

Part of it.

This is the .h file. Is there anything I have done wrong?

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

{

IBOutlet UILabel *locLabel;

}

@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *locLabel;

- (IBAction)pickImage:(id)sender;

@end
```

Comment: It should work what the error your are getting.... just add the breakpoint to check whether the pickImage is getting called or not

Comment: Its not showing any errors but doesn't load for some reason. The debug doesn't seem to be giving me any information as to why its not working other than self=(ViewController*)

Comment: first of all your sender cannot call setImage method as it is of type id without type casting and check whether your btnImage1 is getting nil or not by using Nslog or breakpoint as per your convenience and check also that your loclabel is properly attached 
By putting the background color in both the button and label u can find if they both are visible or not.. they might be hidden due to less frame size or alpha..or anything else.

Comment: It was all working fine until I added "locLable.text = @"Red";" It now won't open the app and sends me to the .h file (which I have now added). But doesn't seem to show any errors.

Comment: You shouldn't define the ivar or use "@synthesize" any more, just declare the property (you'll automatically get an ivar with the name, _locLabel). When you refer to your label, do it with self.locLabel. Also the property, if it's an IBOutlet should be declared as "weak", not "retain". I don't know if this has anything to do with your problem, but you should do it this way anyway.

Comment: This is simply the correct code you just delete your file and add new one than that will work surely don't copy paste as it might copy your error also...

Comment: @Alfa Did as you suggested and it works. However when pressing the button it doesn't change the image to a second image, just changes it to a blue block.

Comment: @PaulH why you have not accepeted my answer if it is correct one..

Comment: @Alfa sorry I didn't realise you had added an answer. You had kind of answered the question the day before in the comments. I will accept now though. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (IBAction)pickImage:(UIButton *)sender {

    UIImage *btnImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SubmitBooking-pressed.jpg"];
    UIImage *btnImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"anyImage.png"];
    UIImage *btnImage3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"anyImage2.png"];

    [sender setImage:btnImage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [sender setImage:btnImage2 forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [sender setImage:btnImage3 forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    locLabel.text = @"Red";
}
```

U can choose what ever your state required. Or your can use combined states by adding simply UIControlStateNormal|UIControlStateHighlighted or UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted